# Rounded cornes (border radius) Safari issue

Tags: html, css

```css
.activity_rounded {
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -khtml-border-radius: 50%;
    border: 3px solid #fff;
    behavior: url(css/PIE.htc);
}
```

```html
<img src="img/demo/avatar_3.jpg" class="activity_rounded" alt="" />
```

This is my CSS & HTML. I want to make an image look like a circle. Everything works fine in IE8+, Google Chrome, and Mozilla Firefox. But Safari is acting kinda strange. Here is a demo picture:

[image]

Comment: Safari for Mac/iOS, or for Windows? It's worth noting that the Windows version isn't supported anymore...

Comment: Safari on Mac. And I cannot figure out why does Safari behave like this...

Comment: If you can change the radius for different browsers seprately then increase it for safari! :)

Comment: It doesn't matter what value I set. I can, for example, do something like 100px (on 40px picture) and no effect.

Comment: If possible, try setting values in px and see if that makes a difference. BTW, you don't need vendor prefixes for border-radius anymore. Also, it could be a safari bug that'll fix itself during an update.

Comment: What size is the image, and what is your base font size?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/v3SNX/ Here a JSfiddle example. Try it under safari.The image size is 40x40px.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

To illustrate the problem in Safari, let's begin with a plain image.

[image]

Here we have an image of 100px x 100px. Adding a border of 3px increases the element dimensions to 106px x 106px:

[image]

Now we give it a border radius of 20%:

[image]

You can see it starts cropping from the outer boundary of the element, not from the image itself.

Further increasing the magnitude to 50%:

[image]

And changing the border color to white:

[image]

You can now see how the issue arises.

Because of such behavior of the browser, when creating an image in a circle with a border, we have to make sure both the image and the border are given a border radius. One way to ensure this is to separate the border from the image by placing the image inside a container, and apply border radius to both of them.

```
<div class="activity_rounded"><img src="http://placehold.it/100" /></div>
```

```css
.activity_rounded {
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -khtml-border-radius: 50%;
    border: 3px solid #fff;
}

.activity_rounded img  {
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -khtml-border-radius: 50%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

And now we have a nice circle border around the image on Safari.

[image]

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3XSJN/1/).

Comment: Two points of note: 1. border radius is now well supported to the point that you can dro vendor prefixes. 2. when using vendor prefixes, state the generic after all vendor specific ones. Great answer to this question, btw!

Comment: @Antony Hmm. So, Safari says "50% radius" is (in this example) `50px`, and therefore the flat edges are the `12px` of "leftover" border? Which would imply that Firefox et al must be calculating the radius as `53px`? Perhaps leaving the markup as it was but changing the `box-sizing` would work as well? Almost makes me wish I had a Mac to test this on...

Comment: @TiesonT. Sounds reasonable, but changing `box-sizing` has no effect on Safari. Just tested it.

Comment: @Antony Fair enough. Will have to keep this behavior in mind. Thanks for checking.

Comment: Does anyone know if this is fixed in later versions of safari?  I only have 5.x to test with.  What version fixed it?

Comment: @Julian It appears to be fixed in [Safari 7.0](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ErYip.png).

Comment: irrelevant to my quest but +1 for the absolutely brilliant answer.

Comment: what if i use border: none; why the same result appears?

Comment: @ПавелИванов Do you have a fiddle? But I am already using Safari 7 so I may not be able to reproduce it.

Comment: Doesn't work on iOS 11. I guess that means it's a feature that Apple don't want you to fix.

Comment: @Reado I have tested with iOS 11 on an iPhone X. `border-radius` works fine on images whether you apply it on an image directly, or over a container like I do. When you say it doesn't work, can you create a fiddle?

Answer (score 40):

Seems this one works:

```
.wrap{
   -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
   -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle, white 100%, black 100%);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qWdf6/82/

Comment: Worked for me, except I didn't use `-webkit-transform` and I added `border-radius: xx%`

Comment: Same thing but with `clip-path`: `-webkit-clip-path: circle(50% at 50% 50%);`

Comment: for me, I just needed the `translateZ(0);`

Comment: Hi everyone, if it works for you, What's the black magic under the surface of the mysterious `transform: translateZ(0);`? If I don't understand it, How can I write it in my production codebase irresponsibly?

Answer (score 4):

Try this by adding `overflow: hidden;` to the set of rules. This is an issue with all the webkit browsers:

```css
.activity_rounded  {
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
     -khtml-border-radius: 50%;
       -moz-border-radius: 50%;
            border-radius: 50%;
    border: 3px solid #fff;
    behavior: url(css/PIE.htc);
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I tried in Safari 5.1 under windows and it didn't help solve the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Add the following CSS Code to the root html element:

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: This solution worked for me with only -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); Which is interesting because if I understand correctly this is moving the image 0 px? Also I was able to add this at the image level and not the root level.

Answer (score 3):

Just simply use `box-shadow` if you don't care the old browsers.

```
.rounded {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px pink;
}
```

Comment: In Aug 2020, this was by far the easiest implementation to get a small border working around a Semantic React UI Table.

`box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 0.5px #fff;`

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the longhand markup?

```
-webkit-border-top-left-radius 
-webkit-border-top-right-radius 
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius 
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius
```

It seems like there are some bugs on using the short-hand notation with some versions of Safari.

Comment: I tried in Safari 5.1 under windows and it didn't help solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Simple way i did was use rounded PNG images and apply a border and radius of 50%

example :

http://www.laugfs.lk/#ourbusiness

Answer (score 2):

If the image's border radius is set the same as its parent div, the accepted solution works fine for circular images but not rounded rectangles because the width of the image is less than that of its parent div and the border radius needs to be scaled in proportion to the image, otherwise the image will appear more rounded than the parent div and there will be a gap between the inside edges of the parent div and the outside edges of the image.

However, if you can specify your div/image widths in absolute dimensions it's possible to set a border radius for the image so that it will fit exactly inside its parent div, by taking into account the border width.

HTML:

```html
<div class="image-container-1"><img src="my_image.jpg" /></div>
<div class="image-container-2"><img src="my_image.jpg" /></div>
```

CSS:

```css
.image-container-1 {
    border: 6px solid #FF0000;
    border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    height: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 250px;
}

.image-container-2 {
    border: 6px solid #FF0000;
    border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    height: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 250px;
}

.image-container-2 img {
     border-radius: 14px; /* 20px border radius - 6px border */
     -moz-border-radius: 14px;
     -webkit-border-radius: 14px;
     height: 250px;
     width: 250px;
 }
```

RESULT:
[image: Border radius clipping example for Safari 5.1.0 and Firefox 35.1.0]

This solution was also tested in Internet Explorer 9 and Chrome 43 and the results were the same.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of putting the border on the image itself, put it on the container. Make sure the border-radius is on both the image and the container

```
.img-container {
    border-radius 100%;
    border: solid 1px #000;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.img {
    border-radius: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## 2023 Version:

`clip-path` shape syntax is now generally available across all modern browsers.

I ran into this same problem on Safari with it not clipping overflowing contained pseudo-elements.

Using `clip-path: content-box` *should* solve most use cases in safari:

```css
.my-class {
  border-radius: 50%; /* or whatever */
  clip-path: content-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

[See here for more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path)

Comment: This is the preferred way to clip the overflow in Safari.

Answer (score 1):

Ammend to Lesbaas 2023 Answer:

Use view-box for clip-path if you want to have a border around the div

`clip-path: view-box;`

Answer (score 0):

But if you have a border with radius on a div and inside it you have dynamic content (like if you click on that div, it slides down and show some other content), and you want to redesign your border with the same radius, you can use an aux class that redraw the radius (but the hack is that if you don't change the colour of the border the webkit will not redraw it).

Eg:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.parent', function(e){ $('.content').toggleClass('opened').slideToggle(300);
 $(this).toggleClass('refreshBorders');
});
```

```css
.parent{
cursor:pointer;
text-align:center;
-webkit-border:2px solid black;
-moz-border:2px solid black;
border:2px solid black;
-webkit-border-radius:50px;
-moz-border-radius:50px;
border-radius:50px;
-webkit-background-clip:padding-box;
transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
}

.content{
text-align:center;
display:none;
}
.opened{
display:inline-block;
}
.refreshBorders{
-webkit-border:2px solid red;
-moz-border:2px solid red;
border:2px solid red;
-webkit-border-radius:50px;
-moz-border-radius:50px;
border-radius:50px;
-webkit-background-clip:padding-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">

 <div class="first">
  <h1> title </h1>
 </div>
 <div class="content">
  <p> content content content</p>
 </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

do not use the `position:relative|absolute` style attribute for your `overflow:hidden` 
 rounded corner item

for example

```
<style>
.rounded_corner_style
{
background-color: #00FF00;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius:100px; /* you can also use border-radius:100% | border-radius:2px*/
}
</style>

<div class="rounded_corner_style">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kgblc.png" style="height:100%"/>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If any one still facing this issue.
Just include

```
-webkit-mask-image: radial-gradient(circle, white 100%, black 100%);
-webkit-mask-composite: destination-out;
```

To your css if you want to give border-radius to border-image.
My-code: I use styled component you can go with simple css also.

```
export const TicketUpperContainer = Styled(Grid)`
  border-radius: 20px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
  overflow: hidden !important;
  ${(props) =>
      props.status === "upcoming" &&
      `
    border-image: url(${_url("assets/redesign/icons/ticketCardTop.svg")}) 30 stretch;
    border-top: 23px solid transparent;
  `};
  ${(props) =>
      props.status === "past" &&
      `
    border-image: url(${_url("assets/redesign/icons/pastTicketCardTop.svg")}) 30 stretch;
    border-top: 23px solid transparent;
  `};
  ${(props) => `
  background:
    radial-gradient(circle 0px at top    left ,#0000 98%,#fff  ) top    left,
    radial-gradient(circle 0px at top    right,#0000 98%,#fff ) top    right,
    radial-gradient(circle ${props.semiCircleRadius || 30}px at bottom left ,#0000 98%,#fff) bottom left,
    radial-gradient(circle ${props.semiCircleRadius || 30}px at bottom right,#0000 98%,#fff) bottom right;
  `};
  
  background-size:51% 51%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  padding: 16px 24px;
  /**Included code */
  -webkit-mask-image: radial-gradient(circle, white 100%, black 100%);
  -webkit-mask-composite: destination-out;
`;
```