# Border radius is not working in Safari with border

Tags: css

When i put in css Border-radius with border, Its not working properly. If i remove border then its work fine. This issue in on safari browser. See code and attached image.

HTML Code

```
<div class="imgclass floatleft">
<a href="indoor1.php">
<img src="images/led/indoor1.jpg" class="img">
<p>Lamps & Bulbs</p></a>
</div>
```

CSS Code

```
.product-spec .imgclass { width:140px; margin-bottom:45px; }
.product-spec .imgclass p { color:#fff; text-align:center; padding-top:5px; font-size:14px; font-family:'calibri'; }
.product-spec .img { width:140px; height:140px; border:2px solid #bf3c30; -webkit-border-radius: 100px; border-radius: 100px;}
```

[image]

Comment: You missed "px" in -webkit-border-radius value

Comment: That i already changed, Still not working.

Comment: Refer this answer and the explanation :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17202128/rounded-cornes-border-radius-safari-issue

Answer (score 1):

You have to do it this way -> <kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/J2V9v/4/)**</kbd>

I've checked it on my `Safari 5.1.7` (`Windows` version) and it works.

Wrap your image inside a `div` give it a `class` with **the same** `width`,`height` and `border-radius` as your `image`.

**HTML**

```
<div class="imgclass floatleft">

<a href="indoor1.php">

<!-- our wrapper --> 
<div class='div'>

<img src="http://www.openvms.org/images/samples/130x130.gif" class="img">

</div>

<p>Lamps & Bulbs</p>

</a>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.imgclass .div{

 width:140px; 
 height:140px; 
 border:2px solid #bf3c30;
 border-radius: 100px;

 }

.img {

 width:inherit;
 height:inherit;
 border-radius:100px;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try not applying it directly to the `<img>` tag. Try wrapping the `<img>` tag in it's own `<div>`, and adding border-radius to the `<div>` with `overflow:hidden;`.

**1]** Wrap the `<img>` tag it's own `<div>` tag with the class `imgwrapper`.

```
<div class="imgclass floatleft">
<a href="indoor1.php">
<div class="imgwrapper">
   <img src="images/led/indoor1.jpg" class="img" />
</div>
<p>Lamps & Bulbs</p></a>
</div>
```

**2]** Add a CSS style for the new `imgwrapper` CSS class.

*Note: I added `-moz-border-radius` for Firefox as well.*

```
.product-spec .imgwrapper { width:140px; height:140px; overflow:hidden; border:2px solid #bf3c30; -webkit-border-radius: 100px; -moz-border-radius: 100px; border-radius: 100px;}
```

**3]** Update the old `.product-spec .img` CSS declaration.

```
.product-spec .img {width:140px; height:140px;}
```