# Safari border radius bug

Tags: html, css

I know there are many related questions/answers, but none of them seems to solve my problem, because my image is inside a wrapping div, but not share the same width/height of the wrapping div (it's wider), thus part of the image stays invisible and if I set border radius to both wrapping div and the image (one of the solutions I've met) it doesn't work.

Here is an example:

[image: Safari clipping]

The blue border is the actual image size, so setting border-radius to the image is applied outside the visible part of the image, which doesn't help.

And here is some css:

```
.image_wrapper {
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0px;
   bottom: 0px;
   left: 0px;
   right: 0px;
   overflow: hidden;
   border-top-left-radius: 27px;
   border-top-right-radius: 27px;
   border-bottom-left-radius: 27px;
   border-bottom-right-radius: 27px;
}
.image_wrapper img {
   width: 288px;
   margin-left: -48px;
   height: 100%;
   border-top-left-radius: 27px;
   border-top-right-radius: 27px;
   border-bottom-left-radius: 27px;
   border-bottom-right-radius: 27px;
   background-clip: border-box;
}
```

A whole example in [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/zopirifutiyu/1/edit) (when open the link click CSS tab to see its content).

So do you have any ideas how to solve this issue? It happens only in Safari and it's really annoying.

Forgot to mention Safari for Windows version 5.1.7

**EDIT: Finally it turned out this bug appears on latest Safari for Windows, which is 5.1.7 and is actually outdated. It appears also on other older browsers:**

- Safari < 6.0
- Chrome < 24.0
- Opera < 15.0
- Firefox < 4.0

Comment: unfortunatly that is in fact a bug since the early ages... You have to give the border-radius the image itself for it to work (with the webkit prefixes ofc ;))

Comment: Safari version? It works fine on Version 7.0.6 (9537.78.2), OSX Maveric

Comment: Forgot to mention Safari for Windows version 5.1.7

Comment: ...Safari for Windows...5.1.7...

Comment: @Pinki I have added border-radius to the image as well, but because it's wider than the wrapping div - the border radius is applied to the invisible part of the image.

Comment: Don't use Safari for windows... its like... agent.........
But if you want to get it up and running, the only way is to make a div container with the height and width of the image and then use the image as background-image of said container. That works

Comment: @Pinki Yeah, I know about this solution as well :) Anyway I don't care about outdated browsers so much. It's important this bug is solved in the recent browsers.

Comment: But the browser you're using is 3 years old (Safari 5 for Windows).
In recent browsers this should be supported i think.
Here's some help anyway ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17202128/rounded-cornes-border-radius-safari-issue

Answer (score -2):

Try using like this:

```
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 27px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 27px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 27px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 27px;
```

It should work now

Comment: Nope, still the same after adding -webkit prefixes

Comment: Did you add them to both selectors?

Comment: @rnevius Yes, I add them to both selectors. Is that wright?