# border not pixel perfect in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari

At [genevalidator.sbcs.qmul.ac.uk](http://genevalidator.sbcs.qmul.ac.uk), the main body div has a border. It has been noted that this is not pixel perfect on Safari version = 7.1 (9537.85.10.17.1).

I'm not too sure why this is. Please take a look at the top of the picture below.

## Border css

```
border: 7.5px solid #5e5e5e;
border-radius: 15px
```

## Picture

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not such thing as `7.5px`. It is unfortunately impossible to render a specific color on half a pixel. 
Either use

```
border: 8px solid #5e5e5e;
```

or

```
border: 7px solid #5e5e5e;
```

Tested on the mentioned Safari version, and it worked like a charm, whereas `7.5px` made a `1px` imperfection on the top border;

Answer (score 0):

Pixel perfection on the web is difficult enough but to also specify half pixels makes it even more difficult. I don't recall how browsers act in such cases, they all round differently in different cases, but you don't give enough information as to what the exact change is and I don't have Safari available to me to double check.

However, there is this answered question about Safari not applying border-radius properly to images as noted here: [Rounded cornes (border radius) Safari issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17202128/rounded-cornes-border-radius-safari-issue)