# Image with border not ideal

Tags: html, css, image, compatibility

I set image border using

```
img {
    width: 25%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 5px red solid;
}
```

And it is supposed to be like

[image]

But on some Android Web defualt Browser on low Android version, it turns into

[image]

My Android version is 4.1.

How to fix this with CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead or `border` use `box-shadow`

```
box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 5px red;
```

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/Lkdyv2jj/5/

```css
img {
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 5px red;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://zhangwenli.com/YooYo/img/avatar.png" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug as far as I know, try this:

```
border-top-left-radius: 5px;
border-top-right-radius: 5px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
```

Or this:

```
border-radius: 10px;
```

Instead of %

Check this http://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius

Known issues:

> Safari does not apply border-radius correctly to image borders:
>   [Rounded cornes (border radius) Safari issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17202128) Android Browser 2.3 does not
>   support % value for border-radius. Border-radius does not work on
>   fieldset elements in IE9. The stock browser on the Samsung Galaxy S4
>   with Android 4.2 does not support the border-radius shorthand property
>   but does support the long-hand properties for each corner like
>   border-top-left-radius.