# Safari appears to be ignoring CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, safari

I'm doing some changes to a wordpress theme, but Safari (both on Mac and iOS) seems to be ignoring some of the CSS, whereas other browsers work fine.

An example - this is how it looks in Chrome and Safari:
https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/cystennin/chrome-safari.png

This is the CSS I've used, specifically for the images.

```
.homeleftside1 img {
width: 70px;
height: auto;
margin-right: 15px;
float: left;
border-radius: 100%;
 }
```

I've got a test site here so you can see what I mean: *link removed*

Any ideas where I am going wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that Safari doesn't support `border-radius`?
Try to add `-khtml-border-radius: 50%;`, that should work... 

Similar question: [Rounded cornes (border radius) Safari issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17202128/rounded-cornes-border-radius-safari-issue)

Comment: No. Safari supports border-radius

Answer (score 0):

Just took a look in Safari and Chrome, but Safari isn't even listing the styles you set in your stylesheet in the list of matched styles for that particular image you're targeting. However, Safari is reporting a couple of errors in your stylesheet: a couple of mismatched curly braces etc. Maybe they are throwing off WebKit? (Would have posted as a comment, but don't have enough rep yet.)

[image: Errors reported by Safari]

Comment: Hi,

I noticed those, but didn't think they were related. I have however cleared those up, with the exception of the font-awesome and bootstrap ones which are apparently caused by compatibility with IE8.

Comment: Safari is just not playing ball at all. I've used the debugger in Safari to apply some styling to a different div. It works in the debugger, but when I edit the CSS, it's totally ignored.
https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/cystennin/Screen+Shot+2015-04-19+at+20.30.05.png

Comment: Hmm, weird. I think that you might have found a bug in WebKit. Have you tried setting the style to a different node? Ie: targetting the same elements on the page but referencing them in a different way. For example, replace `.homeleftside1` with a class or ID of a node that's closer to the target elements in the page hierarchy. Even if this isn't a permanent solution, it'd still be helpful to determine if this is a problem with your code or with WebKit.

Comment: I'm not sure if I am being a cabbage or if there really is something wrong.

I've tried your suggestion and got some movement! Which led me to shift my styling for this content from the bottom of the stylesheet, to the top.
Which resulted in the image taking on the correct styling. Clearly something, somewhere in my CSS is taking priority, despite me using '!important' - which I thought overruled a higher specificity?

With that said, if you look now, you'll see the image is correct, but the text, namely, the price is still wrong. Safari seems to be paying literally no attention to '!important