# image overlapping border in safari

Tags: html, css

I have a pagination with numbers in circles, when you hover on circle corresponding image will display, but in safari the image is overlapping the circle's border..

**Fiddle:-**
http://jsfiddle.net/2yx5e3w1/

**CSS and HTML**

```css
 * {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
    }
    ul li {
     list-style: none;
    }
    a {
     text-decoration: none;
    }
    .pagination_wrap * {
     box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .pagination_wrap {
     float: left;
     width: 680px;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     position: relative;
    }
    .pagination_wrap ul {
     display: table;
     text-align: center;
     width: 620px;
     margin: auto;
    }
    .pagination_wrap li {
     display: table-cell;
     vertical-align: middle;
    }
    .pagination_wrap li a {
     display: block;
     width: 51px;
     height: 51px;
     border-radius: 50%;
     border: 2px solid #dadada;
     background: #e2e2e2;
     margin: auto;
     overflow: hidden;
    }
    .pagination_wrap li a:after {
     content: "";
     display: inline-block;
     height: 100%;
     margin-left: -4px;
     vertical-align: middle;
     width: 0;
    }
    .pagination_wrap li img {
     display: none;
     margin-left: -4px;
     vertical-align: middle;
    }
    .pagination_wrap li span {
     vertical-align: middle;
     display: inline-block;
     font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
     color: #000;
     font-size: 19px;
     line-height: 47px;
    }
    .pagination_wrap li a:hover img, .pagination_wrap li.current img {
     display: inline-block;
    }
    .pagination_wrap li a:hover span, .pagination_wrap li.current span {
     display: none;
    }
    a.prev_arrow, a.next_arrow {
     height: 25px;
     width: 15px;
     background-image: url("http://i9.dainikbhaskar.com/dainikbhaskar2010/images/pagination/slide_nav.jpg");
     position: absolute;
    }
    a.prev_arrow.disabled {
     background-position: left -28px;
     cursor: default;
    }
    a.next_arrow.disabled {
     background-position: right -28px;
     cursor: default;
    }
    a.prev_arrow {
     float: left;
     background-position: left top;
     left: 0;
     top: 12px;
    }
    a.next_arrow {
     float: right;
     background-position: right top;
     right: 0;
     top: 13px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="pagination_wrap">
      
        <ul>
            <li class="current"><a href="#"><img src="http://i9.dainikbhaskar.com/thumbnail/51x51/web2images/www.bhaskar.com/2015/04/07/players_1428406480.jpg" alt="" /><span>1</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>2</span> <img src="http://i9.dainikbhaskar.com/thumbnail/51x51/web2images/www.bhaskar.com/2015/04/07/players_1428406480.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>3</span> <img src="http://i9.dainikbhaskar.com/thumbnail/51x51/web2images/www.bhaskar.com/2015/04/07/players_1428406480.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
        </ul>
   
    </div>
```

Comment: looks fine to me http://s30.postimg.org/5gkmar6yp/Screen_Shot_2015_06_03_at_12_24_00_AM.png

Comment: In my safari:- http://postimg.org/image/67490hm29/

Comment: what version safari?

Comment: version 5.1.7    ..........

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17202128/rounded-cornes-border-radius-safari-issue

Comment: @DipeshRana If you're targeting browser versions that old, it's best if you mention it immediately in the question, without making people ask. Same if you would be having problems in, say, Firefox 10 or IE 9.

Comment: @MrLister For your kind information, version 5.1.7 is latest version of safari for windows... and by the way, do you have any solution to the problem...

Comment: The fact that 5.1.7 is the last version, does not mean you should still target it.

Comment: So what I am suppose to do, should I not check my website in safari ??

Answer (score 1):

Give a border radius of `100%` to both the image and container

```
.pagination_wrap li a,
.pagination_wrap li a img {
        -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
        border-radius: 100%;
}
```

also note that [Safari](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_(web_browser)) for Windows has been discontinued since May 9, 2012.

Comment: we can not give border radius to image, because image can be smaller than the circle or it can be rectangular