# img border + border-radius in safari

Tags: html, css, safari

I'm having trouble with border/border-radius on images in Safari. What I want is for the image to be a perfect circle, so I use border-radius: 100%, and I want there to be a transparent gap between the circular image and a 2px white border, so I create a transparent border that's 11px and add a box-shadow thats white and 2px in size. This works perfectly in Chrome. Here's the example code I'm using:

HTML:

```
<div id="slideshow">
<img src="image1.png">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#slideshow img {
box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2px #bbb;
border-radius: 100%;
border: 11px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

The problem I'm having is that in Safari, the box-shadow shows up perfectly (it's a 2px white circle), but the image itself shows up square instead of circular. What's going on?

Comment: Which version of Safari?

Comment: **Possible** duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17202128/rounded-cornes-border-radius-safari-issue

Comment: ^^ That's perfect! Thanks! Yeah to get that effect in Safari it makes you create a separate container div. Oh well.