# Strange border-radius behaviour in Safari

Tags: css

Using CSS I'm trying to create a curved overlay that will sit within an element and appear on top of its contents.

I've managed to achieve what I want by setting `border-width` and `border-radius` to apply to the bottom left corner. This works fine in Chrome and Firefox but has a strange result in Safari.

What can I do to make it appear correctly in Safari?

### Screenshots

**Chrome (correct):**

[image: Appearance in Chrome]

**Safari (incorrect):**

[image: Appearance in Safari]

### Minimal example

```css
#container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: grey;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#overlay {
  border-color: blue;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 100%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 0 200px 200px;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: -200px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rounded cornes (border radius) Safari issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17202128/rounded-cornes-border-radius-safari-issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to achieve the desired result by making the overlay into an entire circle, then used `calc` to position it correctly. This works correctly in Safari.

```css
#container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: grey;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#overlay {
  border-color: blue;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 200px;
  display: block;
  height: 200%;
  margin-left: -200px;
  margin-top: calc(-200px - 100%);
  position: relative;
  width: 200%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="overlay"></div>
</div>
```