# Border radius for specific corners isn't working on mobile

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use `border-radius-top-left`, etc.m but when I view the page on my phone, it treats it as if it's just border-radius and applies it to all corners. When I view it on my desktop it's working fine.

```
.container {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: calc(90vw - 20px);
    margin: 0 5vw;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.05);
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #ffffff;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    outline: none;
    margin-top: 25px;
    border-top-left-radius: 3px;
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.25);
}
```

Not sure if this is relevant but the CSS is being applied to an `<input>`.

Comment: What browser are you using in your phone?

Comment: @byoigres I've tried Chrome and Safari and it's the same problem on both

Comment: See if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17202128/rounded-cornes-border-radius-safari-issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's okay, probably you are using an old version of browser and it doesn't support border-radius-top-left etc.

But to make sure add this line:

```
border-radius: 0;  // Add this line
border-top-left-radius: 3px;
border-top-right-radius: 3px;
```

Comment: I'm using an iPhone 5 running iOS 10

Comment: add if before :
border-top-left-radius: 3px;
border-top-right-radius: 3px;
this two lines.

Comment: Thanks! Adding border-radius: 0; got rid of the borders that should be normal. I'll accept the answer once it'll let me

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not that the browser doesn't support the shorthand border-radius properties, it's that mobile WebKit browsers apply a radius to all input elements by default. You need to set the border radius of the other corners to zero to remove it:

```
border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
```

Note when using the short-hand for border radius the order is clockwise: top-left, top-right, bottom-right, bottom-left.