# Overflow: hidden + Gif breaks border-radius on safari

Tags: html, css, safari

I want to apply `overflow: hidden` and `border-radius: 50%` to an image to create a rounded border corner.

This question is not a duplicate of [Rounded cornes (border radius) Safari issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17202128/rounded-cornes-border-radius-safari-issue). My problem only occurs when the image is a gif.

However, it breaks on safari when the image is gif. I can reproduce the problem more often on retina screen. My safari version is 11.0.2 (13604.4.7.1.3).

```html
    <body style="background: black">
      <div style="width: 200px;border-radius: 50%;border: 4px solid white;overflow: hidden;">
        <img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/o0vwzuFwCGAFO/giphy.gif" style="width: 100%">
      </div>               
    </body>
```

What I see on safari is broken border.

[image]

I have tried `transform: translate3D()` to create new render layer and [`mask-imge`](https://qiita.com/nabettu/items/8847e690758e280ee3bc) to work around the problem. However, they don't work either.

Thanks in advance for other work around!

Comment: Here ya go, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17202128/rounded-cornes-border-radius-safari-issue

Comment: @Jeremy I have read that answer before asking and it didn't work.

Comment: I'm as frustrated as the kitty in the gif, btw.

Comment: Wait, can't you just make the `border-color: transparant;`?

Comment: Because I do need a white border around image.

Comment: Does this one work? http://jsfiddle.net/jpy3v8c4/1/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168107/discussion-between-herrington-darkholme-and-jeremy).

Comment: any fix/workaround so far? :(