# Border appears within image rather than around the image

Tags: python, html, css, imgkit

So basically, I am trying to add a border to an image and screenshot it using img-kit via python3. I applied a border-radius and an actual border. However, the border appears inside the image, not around the object.

Here's how it looks;

[image]

I tried some examples from stack overflow like adding padding or margin but it didn't work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Profiles | Nekotony</title>
      <style>
         @font-face {
         font-family: 'keepcalm';
         src: url('/home/alice-bot/storage/KeepCalm-Medium.ttf')  format('truetype');
         font-weight: normal;
         font-style: normal;
         }
         body {
            background-color: #1C1C1C;
         }
         .profiles {
         background: url("https://i.imgur.com/0Hl2D6w.jpg") no-repeat;
         background-size: 100%;
         width: 1650px;
         height: 500px;
         background-color: #1C1C1C;
         position: fixed;
         }
         * {
         margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box;
         font-family: 'keepcalm', Fallback, sans-serif;
         }
         .img {
         margin-top: 25px;
         margin-left: 25px;
         width: 450px;
         height: 450px;
         border-width: 5px;
         border-color: #000000;
         border-style: solid;
         border-radius: 250px;
         } 
      </style>
      <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-type">
      <meta content="png" name="imgkit-format">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="profiles">
          <img class="img" src="https://i.imgur.com/X2XG1tU.png">
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

```py
import imgkit
import jinja2
import string 
    def final_image(self, user):
        html = self.render_template('final.html')
        by = imgkit.from_string(str(html), False, options={"width": 1650,"height": 820,"crop-w" : 1650})
        return by

    def render_template(self, file_name,**context):
        return jinja2.Environment(loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader('/home/alice-bot/storage/')).get_template(file_name).render(context)
```

Comment: Which browser are you using? - works just fine in Chrome, Edge and Firefox for me

Comment: I'm screenshoting it using imgkit. https://pypi.org/project/imgkit/ @Ballard

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17202128/rounded-cornes-border-radius-safari-issue That helped me fix this.

Comment: was it -khtml-border-radius: 50%; ? @NekoTony