# How to solve this issue with border radius in Safari?

Tags: html, css, safari

The border is applied to the video, but the video is not exactly inside the border.
How can I fit it inside the border? The issue is only in Safari. I have added a link to show it more clearly.

[Safari then 2nd is Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYTdH.jpg)

Below is the CSS.

```
   .video-div
 {  
     justify-content: center;
 }

 video {
     overflow: hidden;
     height: 100%;
     width: auto;
     border: 6px white solid;
     border-radius: 50px;
     position: absolute;
     right: 50%;
     left: 50%;
     transform: translateX(-50%);
 }
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think it would be nice if you added the html that this pertains to.

Comment: Post your HTML and complete CSS along with images so this can be reproduced.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rounded cornes (border radius) Safari issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17202128/rounded-cornes-border-radius-safari-issue)

Comment: There is some issue with me sharing the entire files. Can't do that. And my issue is a bit different than the one that has been solved before.

Answer (score 0):

I think Yo get solution from here:

[Rounded cornes (border radius) Safari issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17202128/rounded-cornes-border-radius-safari-issue)

```
html:
<div class="activity_rounded"><img src="http://placehold.it/100" /></div>

css: 

.activity_rounded {
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -khtml-border-radius: 50%;
    border: 3px solid #fff;
}

.activity_rounded img  {
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -khtml-border-radius: 50%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```