# Why wont css transition for border radius work in safari?

Tags: css, safari, webkit, css-transitions

Im trying to make a simple transition for some pictures on my site. The idea is that the pictures are circles and when you hover over them they transition into squares. This works perfect on chrome and firefox, but I just cant get it to work on safari. Here is the css:

```
.bild {
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: 95%;
  width: 95%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-transition-property: border-radius;
  -webkit-transition-duration: .8s;
}

.bild:hover{
  border-radius: 0%;
}
```

Comment: start by removing the -webkit-, it's not more needed

Comment: I removed the -webkit-, but it still wont work.

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17202128/rounded-cornes-border-radius-safari-issue