# Problem with complex border-radius on owlCarousel and some browsers

Tags: html, css, safari, mobile-safari, owl-carousel

So, in this case, by design I was required to do some elements that had either a concave or a convex side, achieved by complex `border-radius`. Now,  because `border-radius` ends up creating an ellipse of the element or half an ellipse, in order to achieve the final look, which looks like this...

[image: Image example]

... I had to create a wider container which houses the whole radiused element, but only shows a part of it.

What I basically do is have a main container with `overflow: hidden` (`#main-slider`) in which I create an element (`#main-slider-holder`) that has `width: 130%;` and is moved 15% to the left `margin-left: -15%` and also has the `border-radius` class `.bottomcucurve`. It also has `padding: 0 15%;` so that its child element can be centered inside.

In the end I have the `#slider` element inside and that's where the content is. The slides have a specific height and they determine the slider's height.

Everything works fine, except for when I open it on an iPhone (Safari and Chrome) or on a Mac Safari. Mac Firefox and Chrome work fine, but Safari doesn't.

The issue is that basically it does show the complex border-radius on static elements, but specifically on elements of owlCarousel instances, it just decides to ignore it and the `overflow: hidden` of the parent container and just shows the complete elements.

Basically this happens:

[image: Second image example]

You can see the curved part below, but the content of the slide doesn't get clipped as it should.

The structure I have is the following. You can see it in action [here](http://www.gspc.mx/).

```css
#main-slider {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 120rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 4;
}

#main-slider-holder {
    height: 100%;
    background: #248942;
    width: 130%;
    margin-left: -15%;
    padding: 0 15%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#main-slider .slide {
    height: 17.5rem;
}

.bottomcurve {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 59.5% 8.75rem;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 59.5% 8.75rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-slider">
    <div id="main-slider-holder" class="bottomcurve">
        <div id="slider">
            <div class="slide">Slide 1</div>
            <div class="slide">Slide 2</div>
            <div class="slide">Slide 3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there something I am missing here? How should I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

These links might help you solve:

https://forum.webflow.com/t/overflow-hidden-round-corners-not-working-on-safari/67805

https://forum.webflow.com/t/safari-not-hiding-overflow-on-rounded-corner-divs/55060

Comment: I think you didn't read my question thoroughly, this works, the problem occuring is related to either overflow or z-index. Also, you should read this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius

Comment: The thing you want to implement can't be implemented by using border radius

Comment: maybe this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17202128/rounded-cornes-border-radius-safari-issue

Comment: As I told in the question, the border-radius in question works on elements that don't have owlCarousel. It only fails on elements that are inside an owlCarousel. And what fails is not the border-radius, because the parent element still has it.

Comment: It's because the owl carousel css overrides the other css files meaning that you have to prioritize your code not the owl carousel. Try changing the owl coraousel file that has the border radius with the value you want. Do you under what i'm trying to say? When you add a library for example bootstrap the browser might priorotize the library instead of your code. So it ignore your border radius value and uses the owl carousel border radius value.

Comment: Again, this is not the case, the main container has overflow: hidden and in all browsers it has the border-radius. The problem occurs when owlCarousel loads, the border itself works, but the slides are the ones having some sort of overflow issue.

Comment: And that only happens in Safari and iOS browsers.

Comment: Maybe try this solution https://forum.webflow.com/t/overflow-hidden-round-corners-not-working-on-safari/67805

Comment: Also this https://forum.webflow.com/t/safari-not-hiding-overflow-on-rounded-corner-divs/55060

Comment: That did solve the problem :) If you update your answer with this I will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to the #main-slider css:

```
overflow:hidden;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
-moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
```

*Thanks to @Mahdyar for finding the solution buried in a forum post above