# Button color and border radius changing when its on phone

Tags: html, css, button, submit

hi guys i have an ecommerce where there is a button, but when its on phone changes color and border radius.

css:

```
//default screen:
//.cart its the wrapper of the submit input
.cart{
    /* position: absolute; */
    bottom: 0;
    height: 4.5rem;
    background-color: #FD6C22;
    width: 100%;
     display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center; 
    border-bottom-left-radius: .5rem;
    border-bottom-right-radius: .5rem;
}

.cart input{
    background-color: #FD6C22;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-bottom-left-radius: .5rem;
    border-bottom-right-radius: .5rem;
}


@media (max-width: 400px){
 .cart{
    /* position: absolute; */
    bottom: 0;
    height: 4.5rem;
    background-color: #FD6C22;
    width: 100%;
     display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center; 
    border-bottom-left-radius: .5rem;
    border-bottom-right-radius: .5rem;
}

.cart input{
    background-color: #FD6C22;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-bottom-left-radius: .5rem;
    border-bottom-right-radius: .5rem;
}
}
```

the color becomes a very light pink, and also the border radius becomes like 5px from all corner,
on pc its all good, also when i inspect and go to phone version its all ok.

this is my button html:

```
<input type="submit" name="prodotti-log" value="AGGIUNGI AL CARRELLO" class="prodotti-log">
```

im using the same input in two pages, with style.css linked with a common header.php, i dont know if its that the problem.

Comment: All of the CSS in your media query is identical to your CSS outside the media query. What's the purpose? It does nothing.

Comment: it was a an attempt to confirm the css, i thought that like this maybe it works, but it didnt

Comment: Well there's nothing in the CSS you posted that would change the color on mobile, and no pink colors anywhere to be seen. It must be in other code you didn't post.

Comment: i have this problem with all of my submit buttons on the website

Comment: how it can be with the code, its all ok in the pc

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rounded cornes (border radius) Safari issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17202128/rounded-cornes-border-radius-safari-issue)