# How to get a round outline on a round <button> with css in Safari

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get a round button which has a an outline in the same color but that doesn't seem to be possible. The outline always ends up squared. Is there a method to achieve that with a  or does it maybe only work with a ?

```css
button {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: black;
  display: inherit;
  outline: 5px solid black;
  outline-offset: 5px;
}
```

```html
<button></button>
```

I have added a picture since this only seems to happen on Safari...[Screenshot from Safari snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkoEs.png)

I need it to work in all browsers especially on mobile though.

Comment: What browser are you using? I'm not sure what the problem is but when I run it in chrome, the button appears as a circle with a border circular border

Comment: When I run th snippet here in Stack Overflow, I see a circle with a circular outline. Seems to work as described?

Comment: Did you try to add margin?

Comment: can you please give us image or reference what shape you want to achieve

Comment: The snippet seems to be cropping it a little. If you add a margin or `position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 100px;` for example you can see it all it's glory.

Comment: @bar9833625 I have a squared outline on Mozilla Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: use an svg or image instead, double borders on a single element is always flaky and never looks right

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this "hack".

**INFO:** In Brave Browser we got a square too with your snippet;

[image]

```css
button {
  position: relative;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: black;
  display: inherit;
  margin:10px 2px;
}

button::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  content: '';
  left: -10px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  border-radius: 40px;
  background-color: transparent;
  display: inherit;
}
```

```html
<button></button>
```

Comment: You're welcome, if this answer is want you want you can accept it :)

Comment: you can add `top: 50%;` `left:50%;` `transform: translate(-50%,-50%);` to after pseudo class to set it at center of your parent element and change your width and height as you outline offset

Answer (score 5):

Safari fixed this bug on Safari Technology Preview 157. Source:  https://webkit.org/blog/13575/release-notes-for-safari-technology-preview-157/

Comment: Any idea when this gets released?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safari-release-notes/safari-16_4-release-notes It's released

Comment: Hmm I’m viewing this page via safari mobile and it’s still square to me

Comment: Are you using Safari 16.4 beta?

Comment: I’m on 16.3.1. I don’t get the beta option. Guess I need to be patient til this comes out :)

Comment: Easily use box-shadow instead of outline https://stackoverflow.com/a/75615947/3826175

Answer (score 5):

For example instead of `outline: 2px solid gray` can be used `box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px gray`. Box-shadow + border-radius works OK in silly Safari. Fixing with ::after is too complicated with in about 10 additional CSS properties.

Answer (score 5):

Workaround is no longer needed.

They finally added it in Safari 16.4:

- Added support for outline following the curve of border-radius.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safari-release-notes/safari-16_4-release-notes

Answer (score -3):

According to your question and code snippet that you have provided. From my browser when I ran both the button and the outline was Circle.

I would suggest you to clear your cache and run the code again OR try changing the browser.

Or please update your question with a screenshot as well, so that we can understand better.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I have updated the question, it seems to be a Safari-only problem.

Comment: [Detaild Answer to the above mentioned Problem, click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17202128/rounded-cornes-border-radius-safari-issue)

Check the link

Comment: @MoinulRobin No, that's a different problem.