# Rounded corners not working in Safari for desktop or mobile

Tags: html, css, rounded-corners

Junior developer here. I am currently having issues with rounded corners in Safari. I have seen that other people have been having this issue as well. Rounded corners is working in Firefox & Chrome but not Safari. It is currently affecting more than one section of the page. The current code for one of them is:

```
#portfolio #portfolio-flters {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto 35px auto;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  padding: 2px 15px;
  outline-style: solid;
  outline-color: #F10086;
}
```

I have tried using "px" as well as "em" to no avail. I have tried using -webkit-appearance: none;, overflow:hidden, and I can't seem to find anything on google to help fix this problem. I will attach photos for reference. The first photo is how it appears in Google Chrome & Firefox (the correct way).

[Rounded Corners](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gk6Bu.png)

Here is how the corners appear in Safari. It also appears this way on mobile devices regardless of browser.

[No Rounded Corners](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCleZ.png)

Any help would be great. I hope I have described this well enough.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is currently a [bug in Safari](https://github.com/Fyrd/caniuse/issues/6099), which will hopefully be fixed soon, where `border-radius` does not affect `outline`. There is a workaround posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69679347/how-to-get-a-round-outline-on-a-round-button-with-css-in-safari), but it is quite hacky and should only be used if you **really need** to use an `outline` instead of a `border`.

Comment: Thank you. I will dig into this more, appreciate it.