# Why does border-radius not take effect on safari browser?

Tags: css, reactjs, safari, border

I am making this card in `react` and using `border-radius` for the profile image. but the `border-radius` doesn't work on safari browsers. I have even used `-webkit-border-radius:50%` specifically for the safari browser.

- [UI screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gK6jB.jpg)
- [CSS screenshot added here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGpUm.png)
- [JSX screenshot added here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8rzk.png)

Comment: Try `overflow: hidden`

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem on Safari (IOS). Can you make your code into a snippet we can run and check that it shows the problem for you. What OS are you on?

Comment: i have tried with overflow: hidden.. but that too doesn't take any effect.

Comment: Safari has a special behavior with border-radius in percentage

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Safari has a special behavior with border-radius in percentage, in this case you should enclose your image in a container and put the border-radius also on the container.

Comment: I have not heard of this before - is there a reference and what problem is exhibited by Safari? I can't reproduce the problem - (Safari IOS) - the image goes circular and with the outline with no problem.

Comment: A good explain here, is not exclusive to safari : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17202128/rounded-cornes-border-radius-safari-issue

Comment: But that phenomenon is not seen on the Safari (or other browsers I have tried) even if I swap border for outline. Do you see it?

Comment: i actually have followed the link you've shared @Mulaga the first time i saw this issue in safari. but to no avail.